# What is rpcuser?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, authentication

Can I just make up a value for rpcuser/rpcpassword in bitcoin.conf? Or do I have to set one up somewhere?

Comment: Does anyone have any resources on how to setup JasonRPC on a bitcoin node (changing the variables in the bitcoin.conf)?

Comment: I cannot post a reply (low reputation ^^) but here are the steps.
1. Open bitcoin core
2. Open "Options" (in french : "Paramètres -> "Options")
3. In the "main" tab, clic the "Open config file" button (bottom left).
4. A window that was empty for me opens, fill it with those 3 lines :
`rpcuser=mysecretusername`
`rpcpassword=1Uphie6diphee6Rur`
`server=1`
4. Save/close file/apply settings.
5. Restart bitcoin core

Answer (score 10):

You can set any values you want for `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in [bitcoin.conf](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf). Those values will be your username and password when you will be connecting to your bitcoind through HTTP JSON RPC. Also be sure to set other important values in .conf file, like `server`, `rpcallowip` and a few others to ensure your server is running correctly and securely.

Comment: What kind of values should server and rpcallowip have? My IP? Or other IPs? Sorry for these questions, I feel like it should be obvious but I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: @Charlie have you followed my link to "Running Bitcoin" wiki page to sample values and their explanations? Server should be set to 1, and rpcallowip to any ips you want to access bitcoind from - set it to something if you want to run it from other computers. If you need further explanations or help with your endeavour, you can drop me a line.

Comment: is there an example file somewhere?

Comment: There is an example file here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf

Answer (score 1):

No you can define the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in the `bitcoin.conf` file itself. Usually it is commented, you can uncomment the line `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` and input your username and password which will be used when you will be connecting to your `bitcoind` through HTTP JSON RPC.

[image]